# get href value of the first anchor for each element

Tags: javascript

I am trying to extract the links of the rss feeds froms https://blog.feedspot.com/hr_rss_feeds/

I just need to run the script in the DevTools console and get the output.

The script I came up with is

```
var selects=document.querySelectorAll("p.trow.trow-wrap a");
for (i = 0; i < selects.length; ++i) {

      if (selects[i].getAttribute("rel") === "noopener nofollow")
      {
        console.log (selects[i].item(1).href);
      }
}
```

The problem is, it gets the url of both **RSS Feed** & **Site**

I only need the urls of **RSS Feed**. How can I `console.log` the first anchor or `selects[i]` (on each loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following doesn't seem to be perfect but provides fairly consistent output

```
const feedLinks = [...document.querySelectorAll("p.trow.trow-wrap")].map(el=>{
  return el.querySelector('a').href
})
console.log(feedLinks)
```

Comment: This is a close to accurate answer. I got 129 out of 150.

Comment: Wasn't really willing to spend the time to find the anomalies to be honest

Comment: Can you please explain what this code is doing.

Comment: The `[...doc.queryAll]` part turns the nodelIst of `<p>` into an array and is same as `Array.from(doc.queryAll)` . Then uses Array map() on those elements and returns href of first `a` in the `<p>`

Answer (score 0):

OP here, the code that is working for me is:

```
var selects=document.querySelectorAll("p.trow.trow-wrap");
for (i = 0; i < selects.length; ++i) {
        console.log (selects[i].querySelectorAll("a")[0].href);
}
```